Is my plan to replace a 1960s service panel reasonable?
I recently bought a fixer upper house from the 60s. The mold test came back positive in some areas of the house (windows being one of them) and they recommend checking behind the drywall underneath the windows because there’s evidence of leaks. The house has lead-based paint and we are buying the remediation tools for the mold which are similar for lead-based paint and we have to get behind the drywall anyways. So, we figured we would rip out the drywall to deal with the lead-based paint as well. The house has aluminum wiring and we figured since we are tearing out the drywall then we might as well just replace the wiring. So, in my jurisdiction (New Mexico) I cannot pull a permit until I pass a homeowners exam, which I plan on doing.
We will be living at the house during renovations so no power is not an option. (Will I have to run on a generator?)

What are the best steps if our panel is not up to code (no main disconnect and double tapped neutral bus bars plus whatever else) and we want to run copper a room at a time (remove drywall, deal with mold, run copper, put up drywall, paint, flooring)?
Do we need to have an inspection before we put up drywall?
The idea that we think we need to do is,
Apply for and get permit

Pigtail aluminum wiring, install GFCI outlets
Utility disconnect service
Replace panel, install GFCI and AFCI breakers
Connect to generator for power to house while waiting, rough inspection, reconnect to utility service
Turn off breaker, rewire room with copper, rough inspection, hang up drywall, turn on breaker
REPEAT 5. FOR ALL ROOMS (total of 10)
Final inspection

Rough inspections: 11
Final inspection: 1
Total inspections: 12
Is this plan good or stupid? Is there a way to make this more efficient and cut down on inspections and avoid pigtailing and the need for a generator while keeping our goals?
Also, are we wasting our time and money running copper if we have to pigtail anyway? I’m 24 and I want this to be a home that I can pass to my kids and grandkids and hold value hence why I want to run copper.
Let me know your thoughts.
Cheers!
Branch Wiring Noted:


The report snippet you posted only talks about the main feed conductors being aluminum, which is normal and fine.  Can you post what you're basing your deduction that the branch circuit wiring is aluminum?

@ThreePhaseEel Included photo from report, also had electrician check wiring that connected to outlets and further confirmed branch circuit wiring is aluminum and not pigtailed

One easier way to do this can be to install the new panel, then re-feed the old panel from the new panel. Generally this can be done as a one day (4 hour or less) cutover so there is no need for a generator.

Not certain as far as reducing the number of inspections, though. Bear in mind that you can do work for both sides of a wall if you open up one wall; it doesn't have to be strictly room-by-room.

Double-tapped neutral bus bars is the easiest thing in the world to fix.  I could teach you in 10 minutes.  Worst thing it might mean is adding an accessory ground bar to move some grounds off the bar.

A few things to consider:

Pigtailing does help if and only if (a) you use the right kind of connectors (e.g., Ideal purple) for pigtailing and (b) the devices on the ends are not aluminum compatible. Generally speaking the breakers are OK with aluminum and the issue is switches and receptacles. For example, in a quick search I found this Leviton CO/ALR receptacle at Home Depot. So it may be a lot easier and cheaper to simply switch the receptacles and switches and only pigtail where there are devices that can't be easily replaced with aluminum-compatible ones.
For lead paint, the easiest thing to do is to paint over it. It is when you sand it, cut it, etc. that you have to deal with disposal, etc. If you have to replace drywall due to mold then you have no real choice in the matter, but otherwise, cover it and you're done.
GFCI and AFCI generally only have to be added when you make changes or add new circuits, not for direct replacement of existing circuits (grandfathered). GFCI in key areas - kitchen and bathroom - is a cheap and easy fix and highly recommended for safety. But for other locations and for AFCI you may not want to bother if your jurisdiction requires it.
Panel replacement can be done with minimal downtime, generally less than a day. That's typically by installing a new big panel (minimum 30 spaces, 40 or 42 is even better) next to the old panel and either transferring utility power to new and feed old from new or feed new from old until you are ready to transfer utility power to new.
The key with aluminum wiring is to torque to spec - every breaker, neutral bar, receptacle, switch, etc. will have a specification. Doing that helps alleviate most of the safety concerns.
As far as when/where/how you will need inspections, when you go for the exam (or even better, before you go for the exam in case it is an exam question) talk to the permitting office about how things work, as it can vary a bit by jurisdiction and type of work (renovation vs. new).

